# Core Data Error Message: binding not implemented for this SQLType 7

Tags: iphone, core-data

The below exception is thrown on the iPhone simulator when attempting to save a Core Data SQLite store after deleting existing records using `[managedObjectContext deleteObject:object];`

> NSInternalInconsistencyException,
>   reason: binding not implemented for
>   this SQLType 7

The entity for the records being deleted consists of just strings, ints, bools, and doubles.  This is only an intermittent problem.

What does this error mean?

Comment: Does the object have any relationships? If so, what is the delete rule on those relationships?

Comment: It has no relationships, just attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was caused by an incorrect mapping model from one core data model to the next, and would only happen when values were changed in the incorrectly mapped table/column of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a quote (`'`) -- the error is showing `7'`